# CATiledLayer redraw of underlying subview

Tags: uiview, core-animation, calayer, catiledlayer, setneedsdisplay

I have two subclassed UIView as subviews of UIViewController's view. 
First UIView has CATiledLayer as a layer class. And it placed on background. Second UIView placed above first. I want to redraw UIView with CATiledLayer. I've tried to call [myView.layer setNeedsDisplay] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all **CATiledLayers** use for drawing the same thread(s) or interfere somehow else. All **CATiledLayers** will be drawn serially from back to front.